# How do I came to know whether user downloaded my app or not in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have fetched "facebook friends" in a `UITableview`. Now I want to send requests to my those "facebook friends" whose had not downloaded the app to download the app and the push notification to other friends who had already downloaded the app to join the restaurant table in my restaurant app.

1. Firstly I need to know how can I came to know which user downloaded my app or not?
2. And second how to send request to my "facebook friends" to download the app?

I am very new in iOS. I read many tutorials but couldn't found the exact answer.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the friends who have installed your application by using facebook graph API.

###########//latest edit//

here you go:

//take the permissions first for what you want to fetch really//

```
 `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     if(!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen)
     {
          [FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility: YES];

         {
              [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(large)",@"fields",nil] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
               {

             //[self request:FBRequest didLoad:result];

             NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; 

  //@"data" contains all your friends who installed the application

             NSLog(@"------>%@", friends);

             arrayFbIDS =[friends valueForKey:@"id"];
```

//take out the facebook IDs from @"id" string

`

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in the iOS SDK to know who downloaded an app. You might be able to use the Facebook SDK to find which friends installed it via a published link to it in Facebook.